# Will transaction isolation level resolve race condition in multi-threaded webapp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nhibernate

I'm a bit confused what to do, I have a web application which handles incoming requests in multi-threaded way (so that is almost certain some requests are processed simultaneously). 
Now there is a requests which creates/updates a plan for a day.

Here are the steps for the request handling (pseudo-code, the webapp is written with NHibernate but I don't think it matters here.)

```
begin transaction

day_id = select id from day where day.date = request.date
if not day_id:
    day.date = request.date
    insert into day ...
    day_id = last insert id
plan.day_id = day_id
insert into plan ...

commit
```

when two requests are handled simultaneously, there is an obvious race condition:

```
+------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Step |           Request1           |             Request2              |
+------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1    | begin transaction            |                                   |
| 2    | select Day.id where date=:d  | begin transaction                 |
| 3    | not found, insert            | select Day.id where date=:d       |
| 4    | plan.day_id = last_insert_id | not found, insert                 |
| 5.   | insert plan                  | plan.day_id = last_insert_id      |
| 6.   | commit                       | insert plan                       |
| 7.   | commit OK                    | commit                            |
| 8.   |                              | commit NOT OK, duplicate Day.date |
+------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I've tried setting transaction isolation level to serializable, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem (and I'm not even sure it was supposed to solve ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your racing condition is not caused by what request gets stored first. It's caused by two requests being around at the same time.

If your requests are created on your side you need a better way to choose jobs for your threads.If the requests are not created by you than just handle the exception nicely.

The transaction failed, there's not bad data in your database so what's the problem?

Comment: Dispatching requests to the threads is handled by an external framework. Indeed, the data is consistent so it is not about transaction isolation, but rather table locking or something like that. Anyway I don't think "just handling an exception" is the solution here ;)

Comment: It is the solution. at least until you say what you want to do when you have duplicates. Overwrite? Say everything is okay?
There is no magic db control that will somehow make those queries not be duplicate.

Comment: I'd like to reference the existing day, if it exists. I'll try retrying the whole process in case of duplicate, as this seems to be better than locking the service section which calls the transaction